# Check the prefix of a number

Tags: javascript, arrays

Let say I have an array of number such that

```
[2,20,10,50,70,100,500,5000]
```

How do I use Javascript to get only those numbers that start with 5 from the array , in that case it would be 50, 500 and 5000 ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```js
const result = [2,20,10,50,70,100,500,5000].filter(num => num.toString()[0] === '5');
console.log(result);
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

```
function GetArrayValues(myList, number)
{
    var result = Array();

    for(i = 0; i < myList.length; i++)
    {
        if((myList[i] + "").indexOf("5") == 0)
        {
            result.push(myList[i]);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: So the only way is to convert the integer to a string first? Would there be any other alternative ?

Comment: @tnkh you can do math to reduce the value and then compare it, but there is no need.

Answer (score 0):

Use `filter`, converting each number to a string and checking the first character:

```js
const arr = [2, 20, 10, 50, 70, 100, 500, 5000];

const res = arr.filter(e => (e + "")[0] == "5");

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`startsWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) and [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to achieve the required the result .

**See demo**

```js
var arr = [2,20,10,50,70,100,500,5000];

console.log(arr.filter(v=>v.toString().startsWith('5')))
```